# 'formatDescription' is only available on iOS 9.0 and newer, Swift

Tags: swift, avcapturedevice

I have some camera controller code in Swift that I've had working for a while, but with the latest version of Xcode and Swift, I'm now getting an error saying that 'formatDescription' is only available on iOS 9.0 and newer with the line:

```
var cleanAperture = CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetCleanAperture(port.formatDescription, true)
```

I don't think this is true. Documentation here ( https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDeviceFormat_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVCaptureDeviceFormat/formatDescription ) suggests that it has been available since iOS 7.0, and there's another SO question from prior to the 9.0 release using the same code here ( [CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetCleanAperture() swift error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24395265/cmvideoformatdescriptiongetcleanaperture-swift-error) )

Is this just an Xcode bug? Anyone know any workarounds? I can't compile at the moment.